# How to check whether html has a head element with BeautifulSoup.

Tags: python

I have  html file:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Using beautifulsoup how can i traverse this html tree , I want to find out whether the head is inside html tag .

I tried this to find html tag , but how to test whether head is inside html now.

```
invalid = """<html>
<html>

</html>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(invalid, 'html.parser')
if soup.find("html") == 1:
    print ('found')
else:
    print 'no html tag'
```

Comment: Did you notice your body is inside your head ? Doesn't that sound unhealthy to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beautiful soup has [a built-in method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names) for this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


invalid = """<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>"""

valid = """<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>"""


def hashead(soup):
    if soup.head:
        print 'found head'
    else:
        print 'no head'

badsoup = BeautifulSoup(invalid, 'html.parser')
goodsoup = BeautifulSoup(valid, 'html.parser')

hashead(badsoup)
# >>> no head
hashead(goodsoup)
# >>> found head
```

Comment: <meta charset = 'UTF-8'></meta> . How do i check whether meta tag contain 'charset' keyword?

Comment: `if soup.meta['charset']:...` See [multi-valued attributes](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes).